# Ruby erb template is removing too much whitespace

Tags: ruby, whitespace, erb

I have the following line in my erb template:

```
SetEnv <%= name %> <%= value %>
```

The output from this line looks like this...

```
SetEnv SomeNameSomeValue
```

There is no whitespace between the name and value items.
I want it to output this:

```
SetEnv SomeName SomeValue
```

I've found lots of articles explaining how to get erb files to strip unwanted whitespace, but I want the whitespace. How do I get the whitespace to stay in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `<%= "#{name} #{value}" %>`?

Comment: That produced the same output (with no space). I must be missing something obvious, as this is making no sense at all now...

Comment: I was right - I was missing something obvious. My data was all screwed up. Now I've fixed my data my original code works correctly, and so does this answer.